# Linq to entities filtering query using persian calendar

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to filter my query using persian calendar month.

my original query:

```
var getNews =
    from gn
    in db.NewsTables
    where gn.Show
    select gn;
```

persian calendar object:

```
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
```

and filtering original query like this:

```
getNews = getNews.Where(nm => pc.GetMonth(nm.InsertionDate) == 9 && pc.GetYear(nm.InsertionDate) == pc.GetYear(DateTime.Now));
```

and the exception:

> base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'Int32 GetMonth(System.DateTime)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression."}

anyone have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean `using persian month`? That the stored date is in one calendar but  `DateTime.Now` returns the date in a different calendar? Or that you want to include all the dates in a month? In the first case, convert `DateTime.Now` to the stored calendar then do a simple comparsion. In the second, do a range search between the 1st and last date of the month

Comment: I store data in gregorian date and want to filter it by persian date, thats it

Comment: Then you only need to convert the persian to Gregorian before the comparison

Comment: Oops, DateTime values are always gregorian. You just need to use PersianCalendar for the calculations and use the range valued directly in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Linq to Entities` only supports [canonical functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738626(v=vs.100).aspx) on its queries. So this is unfortunatedly not supported.

If the dataset is not too large, you could retrieve it completely (using, for example, `ToList()`), then filter it using `Linq to Objects`, just take into account that the whole dataset must be retrieved (and transferred if the database server is not local), and this can arise both memory and performance implications.

Alternatively, if the database records are stored in gregorian date (as stated in the comments), you could make a conversion beforehand... following your code:

```
var gregorianDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 9, 1, new PersianCalendar());
getNews = getNews.Where(nm => nm.InsertionDate.Month == gregorianDate.Month  
                           && nm.InsertionDate.Year == gregorianDate.Year);
```

Comment: This assumes that Linq to Entities will convert the checks to `DATEPART` statements. Even if it does, the performance will be very bad, because this will prevent the server from using any indexes on the date. Note that searching for a month is equivalent to searching for a date range of one month

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it does convert them (the canonical function list include datetime parts)... and I cannot help the performance issues if the check must be done on a `datetime` field and only on a part of them. I'm just following along the OPs code. I'd not use this :-) I guess you could just use a range check, but I'm strictly adhering to the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos by the way, if needed, in SQL server, you can make a persisted index on a computed column, so you could easily make an index out of the date parts if needed (and would perform even better than a range check, at the expense of some storage) :-)

Comment: A query should be avoided If it results in bad performance. The range query is a very common pattern in SQL to avoid using functions. A persisted column would only help to cover the cost of the functions.

Comment: I was not implying otherwise, but I think that's outside the scope of the question. It's obvious that the problem stated in the question is converting the persian calendar date to the stored gregorian calendar one. You could do this in code, in a stored procedure, with or without indexes, using a range check, with persisted computed date parts or evaluated at runtime, etc. As I said, I'm sticking to the scope of the problem stated in the question: I'm saying *why* the OPs code doesn't work, and following it to give a working solution. Just that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to read this question:

1. You want to get all records in a month
2. The stored date is in a different calendar than the machine's date

The first part can be fixed by converting the query to a range query between the start and the end of the month:

```
var startDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(1-DateTime.Today.Day);
var endDate=startDate.AddMonths(1);

var getNews = from gn in db.NewsTables
              where gn.Show 
                && gn.InsertionDate >=startDate
                && gn.InsertionDate <endDate
              select gn;
```

`DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Now` always return Gregorian dates so I assume the search date is entered by the user or through some other means as a Persian Date and the data is stored in the Gregorian calendar.

In this case, you can use the [PersianCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to calculate the range. DateTime values are always in the Gregorian calendar which means that you **don't** have to do anything to convert to Gregorian:

```
var calendar =  new PersianCalendar();
var startDate= calendar.AddDays(searchDate,1- calendar.GetDayOfMonth(searchDate));
var endDate=calendar.AddMonths(startDate,1);

var getNews = from gn in db.NewsTables
              where gn.Show 
                && gn.InsertionDate >=startDate
                && gn.InsertionDate <endDate
              select gn;
```

I'd suggest you used a library like Jon Skeet's Noda Time though, which is aware of calendars and doesn't assume that all local times are Gregorian

Answer (score -1):

The easy (but possibly bad*) answer is to do:

```
getNews = getNews.ToList();
getNews = getNews.Where(nm => pc.GetMonth(nm.InsertionDate) == 9 && pc.GetYear(nm.InsertionDate) == pc.GetYear(DateTime.Now));
```

As Jcl said, the reason for the error is that LINQ to Entities only supports a limited number of functions (that can be translated into expressions that the underlying provider can support). Your `pc.GetMonth` function isn't one that it understands.

By executing `ToList()`, you are forcing the query to execute on the server and return the results. Now `getNews` is just a collection in local memory and any further LINQ operations will be done using LINQ to Objects, which does not have the above limitation.

*This is only a good solution if the **data set is small** before filtering, because the entire result set of the `getNews` query has to be returned and stored in memory before it can be filtered. If it's 20 rows, I wouldn't worry about it. If it's 2000, you should find a way to refactor.

Comment: This doesn't filter anything, it loads the entire table in memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True. Edited to make it more clear that while this is a solution, it's not a good one if the table is large.

Answer (score -1):

Entity translates your code to sql language, and in this situation it can not translate your function GetMonth to SQL. Quick workaround is

```
var getNews =
    (from gn
    in db.NewsTables
    where gn.Show
    select gn).ToList();
```

But this means that you will get all records from database in memory and apply filter after select.

If you show us your function code may be we will be able to help you with filtering directly in database.